# as3 - How to stop video and detach NetStream

Tags: actionscript-3, video, streaming

I have video streaming from the server, and later on I want to add another one just side by side. thats all good, I done that. Now my problem comes when i want to remove video. I manage to remove it from display, but I can hear that video is still playing in the background. So how do I can stop streaming that video?
Here is my code for setting up the video:

```
ns = new NetStream(connection);
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
ns.play(item[1].toString() + ".flv");
video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream( ns );
video.width = 160;
video.height = 120;
videoWrapper = new UIComponent();
videoWrapper.addChild( video );
videos.addElement( videoWrapper );
```

and here is for removing

```
videos.removeElement(myVideos[p][1]); // myVideos[p][1] is a reference of videoWrapper
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drop the connection by calling `video.attachNetStream(null)`, or close the stream with `ns.close();`

It's probably best to do both.

Comment: ok, i cant say that video.attachNetStream(null) not working at all, it works, stops the video, but only when starting any other video. im working on localhost, so maybe the video is already downloaded and thats why its still playing. Anyway, im not sure how to put thaht ns.close(). I have only reference to videoWrapper, so i taked video from that reference with getChildAt(0), but how to get now "ns"?

Comment: The name ns comes from your own code: `ns = new NetStream(connection);` You should keep that instance around. I don't think you can get that from the video instance.

Comment: I'm also curious; why are you adding a component with the video screen in it to the video screen?

Comment: yep, that worked, i just added reference of ns into array and call it from the function where im closing video. Now about your question, im not sure if i understand correctly, because my knowledge about as3 is very minimal. can you explain a bit? Anyway, im adding video into videoWrapper, bacause video is not visible and than videoWrapper is going to videos, what is ID of Group created in mxml.

Comment: It's mostly the last line that looks shady `videos.addElement( videoWrapper );`. It looks like that should create a circular dependency (eg trying to show obj1 which is trying to show obj2 which in turn is trying to show obj1 etc). I'm not that familiar with flex however, so I might be mistaken.

Comment: you might be confused with names, there is just a tree like dependency.
videos -> videoWrapper -> video

Comment: Ooooh yeah, sorry. Video != videos :)

Answer (score 4):

On a **normal video** object, do not call `attachNetStream(null)`, because AS3, later will not let clear the last video frame from the video with `.clear()`
Looks like a bug.
Use `ns.close()`, then use `vid.clear()`, so that the video object can be transparent again.

On **StageVideo**, this is different:
You can call `vid.attachNetStream(null)`, it will remove the last frame too from the stagevideo.
Be careful, it will not stop the playing itself. You have to call `ns.close();`