# How can I remove class completely?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

I have a class file that has some netstreams and connections and I'm trying to remove the class completely. Here's my code:

```
function onTestProcessed(e:CustomEvent2):void {
    // Remove
    rtmp_test.removeEventListener(CustomEvent2.PASS_PARAMS, onTestProcessed);
    e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);

    // Validation comparison
    if (e.boo == false) {
        trace("event.boo = ", e.boo);
    } else {
        trace("event.boo = ", e.boo);
    }
}
```

This code removes the display of video but not its sound. Do I have to find each variable in the class and remove them one by one?

Comment: you need to stop and dispose of the net stream.  What the the currentTarget in your code?

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. trace(e.currentTarget); outputs my class [object RTMP_test]

Comment: That's a custom object, no one can help you unless you share the code from you `RTMP_test`  class

Comment: please have a look at this http://sudrap.org/paste/text/557933/

Comment: thanks for helping. I answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this solved the problem:

```
function onTestProcessed(e:CustomEvent2):void {
    // Remove
    rtmp_test.removeEventListener(CustomEvent2.PASS_PARAMS, onTestProcessed);
    rtmp_test.netStreamObj.close();
    // rtmp_test.netStreamObj = null;
    rtmp_test.vid.clear();
    e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);

    // Validation comparison
    if (e.boo == false) {
        trace("event.boo = ", e.boo);
    } else {
        trace("event.boo = ", e.boo);
    }
}
```

[as3 - How to stop video and detach NetStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660754/as3-how-to-stop-video-and-detach-netstream/15605847#15605847)